# Create custom YouTube-like permalinks for multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm trying to make a permalink-structure like this `https://en.webseite.com/%post-type%/read?v=%unique-key%`

- %post-type%  = for example "article"
- %unique-key% = A unique code like "3uGuivCAuJX" (11 simbols long and A-Z, a-z, 0-9) - like YouTube use

I'm having this permalink structure now: `https://en.webseite.com/article/read-id=%id%` with this function - but it only works for one custom post type. And I need some how to manage database checkups whether a new unique-key gets generated, because there can't be any doubles.

```
function custom_post_rewrite() {

global $wp_rewrite;
$queryarg = 'post_type=article&p=';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( '%cpt_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg );
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'article'   , '/article/read-id=%cpt_id%', false );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_rewrite' );


function custom_post_permalink( $post_link, $id = 0, $leavename ) {

global $wp_rewrite;
$post   = get_post( $id );
$uni_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'unique_post_identifier', true);

if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
    return $post;
    $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( 'article' );
    $newlink = str_replace( '%cpt_id%', $post->ID, $newlink );
    $newlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $newlink ) );        
return $newlink;

}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_permalink', 1, 3);
```

The Problem:

1. This function works only for one post type (I need a array where I can add multiple post types).
2. I want to have this part `?v=%unique-key%` as a querry string but I have no idee how to do this.
3. I need to generate this `%unique-key%` with this function but I need to check the database for double keys

---

```
function generate_content_id( $length = 11 ) {
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

$content_id = '';
for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
    $content_id .= substr($chars, wp_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1), 1);
}

return apply_filters( 'random_content_id', $content_id );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, Do you want this to work for all post types? OR Do  you want to perform database checkups to make sure there are no duplicate Unique-keys?. These are two different questions.

Comment: Yea I know but it's one thing, ... I updated the problems in question

Comment: What did you update? I don't see any edits, are you sure you saved your edits.?

Comment: Now I updated the question - First I wrote the comment, I'm sorry.